# Integrate flow type checker with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, flowtype

I'm using the flow type checker (https://flowtype.org/) for our code.

However, I did not find a plugin for the jenkins build system.

Is there an easy way to integrate flow with Jenkins? So Jenkins will run flow every time there is a commit in github and output a report/or send an email when error found.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jenkins, but if you add the `flow-bin` package to your `devDependencies`, you can just run `./node_modules/.bin/flow check` on CI. I assume you are already installing node modules on CI. If the exit code is `0` it passed.

Comment: hi Nat, thanks for the comment! I can let CI run flow-bin, but it does not send notifications to the developers. And they wont log in to the CI to check. So I was thinking there might be some kind of html reporter or email notification on failure.

Answer (score 0):

- [Install Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/)
- Run `npm run flow check` or similar command in your Jenkinsfile
- If there are errors, the build will fail, you can setup notifications [as usual](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/)
- You can output the typechecking results to JSON with `flow check --json` and [archive the resulting report](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/)